# Groupby for loop to export separate files by group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group dataframe by 'state' column, run calculations on each group, and export to excel with each file being named for the respective state group. If I print the groups, they look correct, but I can't get the files to show the group data correctly. Currently it creates separate files with correct file names, but each file has the complete data set ignoring the groups. 
Source data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-wdmIz_-AILcBqzvpwAFGZfXqhq8oDRrYFVVdkjZ10o/edit?usp=sharing

```
df = pd.read_excel("ranker_test.xlsx", sheet_name='DATA')

grouped = df.groupby('state')

for group in grouped:
    df.to_excel('test files/ranking_{}.xlsx'.format(group[0]), index=False)
```

^This creates the correctly named files, but each file has all states.

```
df = pd.read_excel("ranker_test.xlsx", sheet_name='DATA')

grouped = df.groupby('state')

for group in grouped:
    group.to_frame().to_excel('test files/ranking_{}.xlsx'.format(group[0]), index=False)
```

^Trying to convert it to a dataframe with group.to_frame().to_excel results in this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

How can I convert the groups into dataframes to be stored in each file?

Comment: you need group[1], group is a tuple of index and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've missed a parameter when unpacking the grouped values. The grouped values are a list of touples with the following format (group_index, group_dataframe). So, in order to iterate properly over it, you should do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("ranker_test.xlsx", sheet_name='DATA')

grouped = df.groupby('state')

for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel('test files/ranking_{}.xlsx'.format(name), index=False)
```

Notice the **name** parameter in the for loop

Comment: That was much simpler than I expected... thank you very much